# I have some problems with "RTK Query"

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

recently I've just started to read RTK Query's document in the redux.js.org and understood the doc's main project doesn't show the Posts in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-fermat-cr0yp?file=/src/features/api/apiSlice.js) and just [object Object] is obvioused except of the Posts list which should being loaded by the fake server included in the default project .
secondly I couldn't managed the error in PostsList page (the Page which is included in the redux main project (simple social media)) .

features/posts/PostsList.js

```
 export const PostList = () => {
  const {
    data: posts = [],
    isSuccess,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetPostsQuery()

  const orderedPosts = useMemo(() => {
    console.log(posts)
    const ordered = posts.posts.slice()
    ordered.sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date))
    return ordered
  }, [posts])
```

just got the [] as the posts value then this error appears  "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')"

and the whole the main project of redux is accessible right in this link
[rtk-query-basics](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the following line:

```js
const ordered = posts.posts.slice()
```

It is trying to access a `posts` property on the `posts` array, which returns `undefined` (most likely a typo). This would explain the error message, as `undefined` is not an array, and therefore does not have a `slice` method.

To fix the problem, amend the line to look like this:

```js
const ordered = posts.slice()
```